# jsf with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf

i have two action in my jQuery

```
 <br/> jQuery('#testForm\\:actionButtonA').click();
    <br/>  jQuery('#testForm\\:actionButtonB').click();
```

first make reload page 
 
second only show my dialog panel

how to make that second action waits for finish reload page?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a callback function and trigger the button B click

```
  jQuery('#testForm\\:actionButtonA').click(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/test.xhtml',
    success: function(response) {
     jQuery('#testForm\\:actionButtonB').click();
    }
   });
  });
```